# Include \part* in header with memoir class

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir

When using `\createmark` it doesn't seem possible to make a mark for an unnumbered part (`\part*`):

`\part*{Part}` and `\createmark {part}{both}{nonumber}{}{. \ }` - does not create an unnumbered part heading mark.

There is a workaround for an unnumbered chapter (`\chapter*`) where

`\chapter*[Title]{Title}` and `\createmark {chapter}{right}{nonumber}{}{. \ }` - **does** create an unnumbered chapter heading mark.

What is the best way to get the title of an unnumbered part into the header?

Comment: Only suitable workaround I found is renewing `\printpartname{}` and `\printpartnum{}`.  This does nothing for the starred part function, but suppresses the printing of the part name and number before the title on the title page.